# Java Regex check if string contains XML tag

Tags: java, regex, xml

I am trying to determine if a string contains at least one XML tag using the `String.match()` function. Due to the way the project is set up, I would prefer if I didn't have to use a `Pattern`.

Currently I use this Regex:

```
<[A-Za-z0-9]+>
```

Which obviously only checks if the string has right and left arrow brackets that contains text. What I need is a way to check if the string just has a single XML tag with Regex, eg input like:

```
blah <abc foo="bar">blah</abc> blah
blah <abc foo="bar"/>
```

but not input like:

```
blah <abc> blah
blah <abc </abc> blah
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Use a Find function, I think match implies the regex has to match the whole string. Also, what do you mean by xml _tag_ ? Open, close, or the other forms ?

Comment: @sln Ah, I was under the assumption Regex could also do partial matches. By tag I mean either, it doesn't matter. I just need to validate there is at least one xml node.

Comment: But a _node_ with a closure ? This is not validation.

Comment: @sln Sorry I don't understand? I am just trying to validate that in the provided string I have either `<somenode>` or `</somenode>`. It does not matter if I only can verify there is one or the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
if (input.matches("(?s).*(<(\\w+)[^>]*>.*</\\2>|<(\\w+)[^>]*/>).*"))
```

matches both types of tag (standard and self-closing):

```
<abc foo="bar">blah</abc>
<abc foo="bar"/>
```

without matching incomplete tags like:

```
<abc>
```

See [regex live demo](http://rubular.com/r/jLhnsG9mAK).

Comment: Regex works fine if you add another backslash. So `</\\2>` instead of `</\2>`

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
if (input.matches("(?s).*?<(\\S+?)[^>]*>.*?</\\1>.*")) {
    // String has a XML tag
}
```

`(?s)` is `DOTALL` flag to make DOT match newlines also.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eE3aX3/4)

Comment: This regex fails if the element has attributes.  It is not clear how complex the XML the requester is looking for though.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this regex will match most html/xml tags.
Probably only need node tags, the rest can be peeled off.

Just *node* tags (final edit) -

```
 # "(?s)<(?:/?[\\w:]+\\s*|[\\w:]+(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)+)>"

 (?s)
 <
 (?:
      /?
      [\w:]+ 
      \s* 
   |  
      [\w:]+ 
      (?: " .*? " | ' .*? ' | [^>]*? )+
 )
 >
```

Full -

[Formatted:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 # "<(?:(?:/?[\\w:]+\\s*/?)|(?:[\\w:]+\\s+(?:(?:(?:\"[\\S\\s]*?\")|(?:'[\\S\\s]*?'))|(?:[^>]*?))+\\s*/?)|\\?[\\S\\s]*?\\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\\S\\s]*?)|(?:\\[CDATA\\[[\\S\\s]*?\\]\\])|(?:--[\\S\\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\\S\\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\\S\\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\\S\\s]*?))))>"

 <
 (?:
      (?:
           /? 
           [\w:]+ 
           \s* 
           /? 
      )
   |  
      (?:
           [\w:]+ 
           \s+ 
           (?:
                (?:
                     (?: " [\S\s]*? " )
                  |  (?: ' [\S\s]*? ' )
                )
             |  (?: [^>]*? )
           )+
           \s* 
           /? 
      )
   |  
      \?
      [\S\s]*? 
      \?
   |  
      (?:
           !
           (?:
                (?:
                     DOCTYPE
                     [\S\s]*? 
                )
             |  (?:
                     \[CDATA\[
                     [\S\s]*? 
                     \]\]
                )
             |  (?:
                     --
                     [\S\s]*? 
                     --
                )
             |  (?:
                     ATTLIST
                     [\S\s]*? 
                )
             |  (?:
                     ENTITY
                     [\S\s]*? 
                )
             |  (?:
                     ELEMENT
                     [\S\s]*? 
                )
           )
      )
 )
 >
```