# Java regex to check node/tag pairs in a String

Tags: java, regex

I want to be able to check if a String has the correct "amount" of node/tag pairs similar to XML.

Nodes can be either self-closed, like <something/>, or open-close pair, like <something optional="stuff"></something>, and can have any combination of those in-between, like <something><foo><bar/></foo></something>.

For instance, the following are valid examples:

- blah <abc foo="bar">blah</abc> blah
- blah <abc foo="bar"/>
- <abc/>blah
- <abc>some <xyz> thing </xyz> <klm/>said</abc> blah

The following are invalid examples:

- <abc> blah - abc does not close itself nor has an equivalent closing node
- <abc foo="bar">foo<xyz>bar</abc> - xyz does not close itself nor has an equivalent closing node
- <something> <foo> blah </something> </foo> - open-close pairs not valid due to wrong placement
- <abc <xyz/>>blah - node promiscuity not allowed (in theory this will never happen)

I've tried the approaches written in this thread [Java Regex check if string contains XML tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346991/java-regex-check-if-string-contains-xml-tag) but although they were helpful I couldn't derive a more generic approach due to the fact that I can have any possible number of node combinations.

Comment: Regex doesn't have the power to do this correctly with all cases. You need a parser.

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4935162)